# How can I run two threads in python using their own commands in a Telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to run two threads in python using their own commands from a Telegram bot. How do I do that exactly?

I am using telegram.ext module

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example which is self explanatory. I wrote two command functions. each function has a thread function defined inside it. Then I created a thread object with arguments passed. finally started the threads.

```
import time
from telegram.ext import *
import threading

BOT_TOKEN = '***INSERT YOUR BOT ID HERE***.'


def start(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('Start command going to start the thread 1 now')

    def thread1(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
        while True:
            update.message.reply_text('I am from thread 1. going to sleep now.')
            time.sleep(2)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1,args=(update,context))
    t1.start()


def run(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('run command is going to start the thread 2 now')

    def thread2(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
        while True:
            update.message.reply_text('I am from thread 2. going to sleep now')
            time.sleep(5)

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2,args=(update,context))
    t2.start()


def main() -> None:
    print('bot started..')
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('run', run))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```